# React on Codesandbox - Material-UI refuses to render

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, codesandbox

I was following a YouTube tutorial on how to create a login page using Material-UI, with some modifications.  However, either way I do it, the page refuses to render.  I am doing it on Codesandbox.  I would like to know, is there anything I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I started over, and looking at my console, I am getting this error:
`_csbRefreshUtils.prelude is not a function`

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-sun-ryqf5?file=/src/App.js

This is the video I am trying to follow:
https://youtu.be/L2RnP5vhbdg

Comment: Your codesandbox is in default state. There is no change

Comment: Well, while I was editing it was showing a blank page, which is why I was unable to proceed.

Comment: In that case you can add the code in the question what you did\

Comment: Looks like I got it to work on StackBlitz